# How to pass a value stored in Vuex as a variable in Vuejs 3 (Quasar 2)

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, quasar, vuex4

I'm storing a *date* in a Vuex store (date)

It can be read in a Vuejs (Quasar 2 beta 12 in fact) template {{ date }}.

If I change (mutate) the *date* in the store, the {{ *date* }} changes. Good.

But I also want to run some code on the *date* comparing it with another date (*dateSet*). So I did  ...

```
data () {
    return {
      dateVal: this.$store.state.date,
      dateSet: [a date here]
    
    }
```

and a method would then run a comparison of dateVal and dataSet.

The only thing is that if I change (mutate) *$store.state.date* it changes in {{ *date* }} but not in *dateVal*. Not good.

I'm missing a trick here but I really have looked around the Internet. Advice greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

`dateVal` should be a computed property to listen to the state changes :

```
data () {
    return {
 
      dateSet: [a date here]
    
    }
},
computed:{
    dateVal(){
         return this.$store.state.date
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can import the mapState

```
 import { mapState } from 'vuex'

computed:{
...mapState(['date']
}
```

and use it inside your component